# Android: SeekBar is not updated using a Handler on 4.1.2 Device

Tags: android, media-player, handler, progress, seekbar

friends I am developing an application which is playing small mp3 soundtracks (podcasts). Now my code which I am showing below is working on Android 3.2 as it should. But on Android 4.1.2 the SeekBar is not being updated by the handler instance. I have read about a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12945) in the SeekBar causing this issue but it should be fixed since Android 3.2. Any help or advice would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
public class PodcastDetailFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    private Button playPauseButton = null;
    private SeekBar seekBar = null;
    private TextView timeView = null;
    private int totalDuration = 0;
    private Bundle data;

    private Handler handler=new Handler();

    private Runnable runnable  = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int progress = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

            seekBar.setProgress(progress);

            int hours = ((progress/1000)/60)/60;
            int minutes = ((progress/1000)/60)%60;
            int seconds = ((progress/1000)%60)%60;
            String hoursString = (hours<10)?"0":"";
            String minutesString = (minutes<10)?"0":"";
            String secondsString = (seconds<10)?"0":"";

            timeView.setText(hoursString+hours+":"+minutesString+minutes+":"+secondsString+seconds);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100);

        }
    };

    public static PodcastDetailFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle) {
        PodcastDetailFragment f = new PodcastDetailFragment();
        f.setArguments(bundle);
        return f;
    }

    /**
     * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        data = getArguments();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getView().findViewById(R.id.preparing_track_progress_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            LogUtils.d("Podcast MediaPlayer", "stop() inside the onPause() was called");
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        LogUtils.d("Podcast MediaPlayer", "release() was called");
        mediaPlayer.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }



    /**
     * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its instance number.
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.podcasts_details, container, false);


        TextView dv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.durationView);
            dv.setText(data.getString("duration"));

        timeView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timeView);
            timeView.setText("00:00:00");

            playPauseButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.playPauseButtonView);
            playPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        playPauseButton.setText(getResources().getString(
                                R.string.play));
                    } else {

                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        playPauseButton.setText(getResources().getString(
                                R.string.pause));
                    }
                }
            });
            seekBar = (SeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.seekBarView);
            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                        boolean fromUser) {
                    if (fromUser) {
                        mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);

                    }
                }
            });

            mediaPlayer =new MediaPlayer();

            mediaPlayer
                    .setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
                            seekBar.setMax(totalDuration);
                            playPauseButton.setEnabled(true);
                            try{
                            getView().findViewById(R.id.preparing_track_progress_bar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }catch(Exception ex){
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);

                        }

                    });
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Uri.parse(data.getString("podcast_url")).toString());
            playPauseButton.setEnabled(false);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();






        return v;




    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either use an AsyncTask or a Service (in case the music will play in background) instead of a Worker Thread with a Handler. The AsyncTask is extremely useful with it's onProgressUpdate method, you can use it to update the Bar based on the progress of the audio file.

Here's a basic example of an AsyncTask and how you should use it:

```
private class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    for(int i=0; i<songDuration; i++){
      doSomething();
      publishProgress(i);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    //UPDATE BAR
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    //DO SOMETHING WHEN FINISHED PLAYING
}
}
```

Anyway, here's the official doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I want to update the seekBar each 100 milliseconds displaying the time the track is playing so how do you want to achieve it with an AsyncTask which is used once?

Comment: The asynctask can live as long as you want. You would need to publish progress every 100ms. The fact that the asynctask lives only once has nothing to do with this.

Comment: As you can see the approach with the Handler is not false at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. The SeekBar was ok. It was just the issue that the lenght of a track is only given when you download the whole track. So to show the progress on a SeekBar properly you need to know the length of a track. So you take the length of a track and then call seekBar.setMax(lenghtOfTrack) and the progress is updated as it should by the method setProgress(progress).